# EJB injection returns a null exception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, javabeans

I have a .ear that imports a .jar and a .war modules. I'm trying to inject a EJB on my war that exists in jar, and I'm getting a null pointer exception when I call it. Here's the code.

## WAR PACKAGE

### Controller

This property "private AutenticacaoBean authBean;" is getting a null pointer exception. I don't really know if I need to use @remote in any place, because I'm using different packages, but in the same ear.

```
public class LoginController extends AbstractController {

    @EJB
    private AutenticacaoBean authBean;

    public void execute() {
        //code
    }
}
```

## JAR PACKAGE

### Bean

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class AutenticacaoBean {

    @EJB
    private UsuarioDAO usuarioDao;

    //code
}
```

### Implementation

```
@Stateless
public class UsuarioDAOImpl implements UsuarioDAO {

    public UsuarioDAOImpl() {
        //code
    }

    //code
}
```

### Interface

```
@Local
public interface UsuarioDAO {
    //code
}
```

Any help would be great. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Are you using EJB 3.1 compliant Application Server?

Comment: @VoodooCoder I don't really know, but I'm using WildFly Application Server.

Comment: Are you sure that the LoginController is a managed bean? Is it created by the AppServer? If you create it yourself with LoginController.new() the AppServer has no chance to inject anything.

Answer (score 0):

EJB 3.1 dropped the requirement for local interfaces and you are using AutenticacaoBean without the interface, but probably your Application Server is not compliant about EJB 3.1 and you cannot perform the injection in this way:

```
@EJB
private AutenticacaoBean authBean;
```

You could try to create an interface (AutenticacaoLocal for example) for your `AutenticacaoBean` with the needed methods and then inject this one in your `LoginController`:

```
@EJB
private AutenticacaoLocal authBean;
```

Exactly as you did for `UsuarioDAOImpl`.

Comment: All versions of WildFly released to date support EJB 3.2